# Gradle does not download dependencies for tests defined in custom sourceSet

Tags: build, gradle, build-automation, dependency-management, cucumber-junit

I have the following project structure:

```
MyProject
   --src
   --test
      --acceptance
         --java
         --resources
      --unit
```

and the following build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'

version = '0.1'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src'
        }
    }
    unit {
        java {
            srcDir 'test/unit'
        }
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    }
    acceptance {
        java {
            srcDir 'test/acceptance/java'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'test/acceptance/resources'
        }
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: '*.jar')

    unitCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'

    acceptanceCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    acceptanceCompile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-junit', version: '1.1.3'
    acceptanceCompile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-java', version: '1.1.3'
}


task unitTest(type: Test) {
    description = "Runs Unit Tests"
    classpath += sourceSets.unit.runtimeClasspath
    testClassesDir = sourceSets.unit.output.classesDir
}


task acceptanceTest(type: Test) {
    description = "Runs Acceptance Tests"
    classpath += sourceSets.acceptance.runtimeClasspath
    testClassesDir = sourceSets.acceptance.output.classesDir
}
```

but running 'gradle acceptanceTest' leads to compilation issues as it looks like the dependencies are not found on the classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like in version 1.1.3, the Cucumber class is in package

```
cucumber.api.junit
```

rather than

```
cucumber.junit
```

Changing the import statement seems to have resolved the classpath issue at least.

However, there are issues with running Cucumber JUnit tests through gradle. Further information, and a workaround using a javaexec task is given here: https://github.com/yatskevich/cucumber-jvm-gradle-javaexec. In summary, with the below task:

```
  task cucumber() {
    dependsOn assemble, compileAcceptanceJava
    doLast {
        javaexec {
            main = "cucumber.api.cli.Main"
            classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.main.output +
                    sourceSets.acceptance.output + sourceSets.unit.runtimeClasspath +
                    sourceSets.acceptance.runtimeClasspath

            args = ['-f', 'junit:build/reports/test-results/cucumber.xml',
                    '-f', 'html:build/reports/test/cucumber-tests.html',
                    '--glue', 'com.paragon', 'test/acceptance/features']
        }
    }
}
```

we can now run

```
gradle cucumber
```

and generate the JUnit report.

Answer (score 0):

the syntax

```
srcDir 'path/to/src/dir'
```

is adding an additionally directory instead of replacing the default locations.

instead use

```
srcDrs = ['path/to/src/dir']
```

this should do the trick

cheers,
rene

Comment: thanks for the response - I've tried changing the sourceSets to use srcDirs=[...] but still getting the same error when I run the acceptanceTests target unfortunately.

Comment: "package cucumber.junit does not exist
import cucumber.junit.Cucumber;"                  seems to suggest that there is an issue with the classpath. Is there anything wrong with my syntax in that part of the build file?